# XML::LibXML extracting a value

Tags: xml

This should be incredibly simple. I've been using findnodes quite happily for a while now, but if I just need to extract a single value, I'm not sure it is that efficient.
Consider the following xml document:

```
<document>
   <page>
     <pagenumber>1</pagenumber>
     <detail>bla bla bla</detail>
   </page>
</document>
```

surely, I chould be able to say something like:
$pageno=$doc->"document/page/pageno";
I should end up with a 1 in $pageno?
What is the exact syntax to obtain the correct result?
Is there some sensible documentation with examples somewhere?
Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in PHP class [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) like this;

```
<?php

  $xml = "
    <document>
       <page>
         <pagenumber>1</pagenumber>
         <detail>bla bla bla</detail>
       </page>
    </document>
  ";

  $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
  $pageno = $sxe->page->pagenumber;

  echo $pageno;

?>
```

That will give you your desired result: `1`